# R: Iterate through excel file content readxl

Tags: r, readxl

```
require("readxl")
excelFile<-read_excel("C:/PathtoExcel.xlsx")
```

I want to iterate through the **excelFile** so I get each column's value in each row in the excel sheet how do I do that?

I want to do that for following problem:

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns and 163 rows. The data in each column's row is of type integer that can be 0 or greater. I want to go through Column's rows and count the number of consecutive 0s in a column. Let say I have a column

1
0
0
1
0
0
0
5
0
0
10

so the result would be (2 + 3 + 2 )/3
where 2, 3, 2 are the consecutive 0s in the column

Comment: If you explain in more detail why you would want to do this and what your ultimate goal is you're likely to get better answers.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Perhaps editing your question would be a better way forward than trying to cram everything into the comments...?

Comment: yeah sorry was trying to do that

Comment: You're going to want to read up on the function `rle()`.

Comment: ok thanks but how do I get the column's data to be fed to rle()?

Comment: Something like `rle(excelFile$col)` or equivalently `rle(excelFile[["col"]])`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144859/discussion-between-hariszaman-and-joran).

Comment: Thanks for your help